# Dynamic predicate in XQuery

Tags: xquery, basex

I notice one fact that when predicate has dynamic field to compare then it doesn't work.

For example:

```
  db:open("library")//book[$filterFields = $pattern]
```

for this I get 0 results,

but when I put for example category instead of $filterField then I have some results.

How can I use variable in predicate as field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$filterFields` is supposed to contain a list of element names, you can possibly use the following query:

```
db:open("library")//book
  [*[name() = $filterFields] = $pattern]
```

Comment: Fine. It’s good to have short code snippets, but if you ask further questions, please ensure that your query can be compiled. This generally helps to understand what you are trying to achieve. For example, your code snippet would raise an error because `$filterFields` and `$pattern` are not declared.